# How to use USB-in on an arduino?

Tags: usb

I'm trying to use an arduino as a controller adapter. How would I get USB-in to get the signal from a usb video game controller?

Comment: Google for arduino USB host shield

Comment: Depends on which Arduino you have.  You’ll probably need a USB host shield to read from the controller and you’ll want one of the 32u4 based boards if you want the PC to recognize your Arduino as a joystick.

Comment: @Delta_G The project is to convert a usb controller into a gamecube controller signal. Would a 32u4 based board still be optimal for that?

Comment: You’ll have to explain to me what that means.  This is intended to plug into a GameCube and control that?  That may be a tougher but to crack.

Comment: Yes, that is my intention. I know it will be tough to crack, but I'm sure it's possible, as I've seen people make GameCube controllers out of Arduinos.

Comment: why 32u4? it can emulate a HID device, not read it.

Comment: Maybe better to use a Leonardo as it has a "real USB". So you can "fool" the video game controler and let it belive it's connected to a PC.

Answer (score 0):

It makes actually no sense to plug an USB-Controller via an Arduino to a PC. The direct way and using an autofire/macro /custom key programmer app is more efficient.

- The Arduino UNO (with 32u4) can either replace an USB controller as [demostrated in NicoHood HID library](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID) or
- additionally act as an interface for controller with strange vendor specific plugs [demostrated in UNOJOY](https://github.com/AlanChatham/UnoJoy) and you can build your own Controller/interface out of nearly every old non usb controller by cutting the hardware specific plug (e.g. old Xbox) and attach to an UNO who acts as "interface" to the PC. Another example is a [C64-Joystick to the PC](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/fpfaffendorf/commodore-64-joystick-usb-adapter-c64joy-fc2389)
- The other option for using an Arduino is interfacing with "old video game systems" . For some there are already more or less succesfull projects. When connecting the USB controller via an USB shield you have normally a high lag time due to the USB shield library, so the better approach is to cut the USB plug and directly interface with the Arduino.

Project with USB Host-shield:

- [C64 - with USB Joysticks](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/DocSnyderde/connect-usb-joystick-to-commodore-c64-2fb5ba)

Project old Joystick to USB-PC:

- [NES controller to PC USB](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/nes-controller-interface-with-an-arduino-uno/)

Project Arduino as controller for NES/SNES:

- [UNO to NES/SNES](https://github.com/jtrinklein/SConE)

Info on the [pinout/protocol cn be found in this page](https://github.com/dfanara/NESDuino)

Comment: Pretty much anything is more efficient on a PC, compared to arduino. There can still be many valid reasons for using/building arduino projects.